# Relatório Ireport aparecendo sem dados

Tags: sql, jasper-reports, ireport, jasper

Estou fazendo um relatório com Ireport e passando um parâmetro com intervalo de datas 
meu sql no relatório `SELECT * FROM venda WHERE data between (venda.data = $P{dataInicial}) AND (venda.data = $P{dataFinal})`

Porém, ao testar o relatório no preview, seleciono a data de intervalo no prompt e vem a tela fazia..

Alguém tem alguma ideia ?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ou use:

```
SELECT * FROM venda WHERE data between $P{dataInicial} AND $P{dataFinal};
```

ou use:

```
SELECT * FROM venda WHERE venda.data >= $P{dataInicial} AND venda.data <= $P{dataFinal};
```